# Passing a previously selected value to ROR options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like, when editing a form, for the previously selected value to be selected.  Currently, I am unable to do this.

In my view I have:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :delivery_only %><br>
  <%= f.select :delivery_only, options_for_select(%w[No Yes], '#{@selected}') %>
</div>
```

and in the controller:

```
@selected = store.delivery_only
=> "Yes"
```

What's the preferred method of achieving this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need double quotes to interpolate variables...  This should work.

```
<%= f.select :delivery_only, options_for_select(%w[No Yes], "#{@selected}") %>
```